# if - else statement with two rules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, mouseenter

I want an if statement with two rules, but I'm new to this and I know I'm not doing it right but I hope this gives you an idea what I want.

```
$('.album_tracks_light, .album_tracks_dark').mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('album_tracks_active')(this > span).hasClass('span-not-link'))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).css('background','#282828');
    };
});
```

Basically what I want is, if the two elements that I .mousenter has either the 'album_tracks_active' class or has a span tag in it with the class 'span-not-link', then I want to change the elements background that I .mousentered.

This is the html

```
            <li class="album_tracks_dark">
                <span class="span-not-link"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="album_tracks_light">
                <span class="span-link"></span>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logical or operator `||`

```
if ($(this).hasClass('album_tracks_active') || ($(this).children('span').hasClass('span-not-link')))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: You can use `||` or `or` for or ;)

Comment: I recommend to use spaces between the rules and `||` :)

Comment: Either way, they're essential. If you don't know about logical operators, whatever they look like in your language of choice, you're lacking some pretty basic and important knowledge.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me, I included the html in the question now.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the semicolon after the return false.